# React native community datetimepicker not giving me a datestamp

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native-community/datetimepicker but it's not giving me a datestamp only a timestamp. I've change my mode to date but still it's giving me a timestamp. Here's my code below:

```
{this.state.show && (
      <DateTimePicker
          testID="dateTimePicker"
          timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={0}
          value={new Date()}
          mode={'date'}
          is24Hour={false}
          display="calendar"
          onChange={value => {
             Person.setProperty('birthDate', value);
          }}
      />
  )}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the API of [onChange](https://github.com/react-native-community/datetimepicker#onchange-optional)

```
setDate = (event, date) => {};

<RNDateTimePicker onChange={this.setDate} />;
```

You should do

```
onChange={(event, date) => {
   Person.setProperty('birthDate', date);
}}
```